# Is the sum convergent or not?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need some hint, how to determine if the next sum is convergent or not. $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\sinh n}{(3+\cosh n)^2}$$

Comment: What do you know about $\sinh$ and $\cosh$?

Comment: @DanielFischer I know that it is hyperbolic functions and can be presented as $\frac{1}{2}(-e^{-n}+e^n)$ for $sinh{n}$ and $\frac{1}{2}(e^{-n}+e^n)$ for $cos{h}$. I just cant make my mind how to solve this the easiest way. This sequnce is going to zero as n goes to inf. Just need to make the next step.

Comment: The representations with the exponential function are useful here. Which part dominates for large $n$? Can you find the asymptotic behaviour of the terms using that?

Comment: Argue that the terms go to $0$ very fast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As this is a series with positive terms, use *equivalents:*
$$\sinh n\sim_\infty\frac12\mathrm e^n\sim_\infty 3+\cosh n,$$
hence:
$$\frac{\sinh n}{(3+\cosh n)^2}\sim_\infty\frac{\frac12\mathrm e^n}{\frac14\mathrm e^{2n}}=\frac2{\mathrm e^n}$$
which is a geometric series with ratio $\dfrac1{\mathrm e}<1$. Hence both series are convergent.